# How to use tag-it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tag-it

I am using tagit library from 
      [here](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)
I created the tagit which working correctly and i created the array as follows:

```
    $("#name).tagit({
    itemName: "teamId",
    fieldName: "teamName",
    availableTags: array,
    allowSpaces:true,
    caseSensitive:false,
    removeConfirmation:true,
    placeholderText:"Tag Group..."
     });

           var a =["1","2","3","4"];
```

while using the tag-it all options can be selected correctly ....I want that the tag "4" has to appear as default selection before choosing any option how can i do this..

**Additional information:**

there is a option available in the source to create the new tag

```
       $("#myTags").tagit("createTag", "my-tag");
```

It is also not working for me....

Comment: Did you read all the documentation?

Comment: ya i read the documentation

Comment: Did you notice there is a syntax error in your script on first line after `#name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your problem, there are a couple of javascript errors that may be preventing you from seeing what you expect to see.

- `Define the array before using it`. Secondly, array referred to is named as '`array`' while the array defined is '`a`'.
- `"#name` --> This is missing the closing quote.
- `$("#myTags").tagit("createTag", "my-tag");` is not working before the `id` of your `ul` is `'name'` while you are trying to use `createTag` on `myTags`.

For your first problem, you can use one of these:

(1 and 2 may not be fully utilizing the potential of tagit library.)

**1)** Already initialize your list with an element '`4`'. Something like this in your html :

```
<ul id="name">
   <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

**2)** Create the element '4' already in your html.

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
$('#name').append('<li>' + array[3] +'</li>');
```

**3)** `Use the createTag : $("#name").tagit("createTag", "4");`

Complete working example, with all the options used:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit();

        var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
        $('#name').append('<li>' + array[3] +'</li>'); //Using Option 2
        $("#name").tagit({
            itemName: "teamId",
            fieldName: "teamName",
            availableTags: array,
            allowSpaces:true,
            caseSensitive:false,
            removeConfirmation:true,
            placeholderText:"Tag Group..."
        });
        $("#name").tagit("createTag", "NewTag");  //Using option 3
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="name">
       <li>0</li>  <!-- Using option 1 -->
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I resolved the problem, the error is when i create the tag using  createTag i suppose to give the tag which is already in the availableTags array....But i wasn't ...So changing this clears the error..... I will accept your detailed answer