# Prepopulated tag using an array instead un orded list

Tags: jquery, tag-it

Using jquery [tagit](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html) for tag functionality. As per there documentation they are suggesting to use the predefined unordered list(li) for pre-populated tags. But I wish use an array instead of "unordered list", can someone suggest any solution?

```
<ul class="tagit">
<li>Java</li>
<li>Php</li></ul>
```

Trying to use like below.

```
var preTags = ["Java", "Php"];
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022016/how-to-use-tag-it

Comment: Now I got .tagit("createTag", "NewTag"); but not sure it support for an array.

Comment: $("#inputboxid").tagit("assignedTags") this will fix it..

Answer (score 0):

That would be tough.

But a better option would be :

When the user submits the form, at the js handle the event and construct the array like below:

```
$(".submit").click(function() { // this could be submit button or onblur event also
   var tags = [];
   $("ul.tagit li.tagit-choice").each(function() {
        var individualtag = $(this).find("span").text();
        tags.push(individualtag);
    });
});
```

for tagit use the following:

```
$("#inputboxid").tagit("assignedTags")
```